# How do I replace the date with a writable title?

Tags: iphone, date, title

When I add a new row, it currently adds a new row with the current date as the title. Below is the code that I have. What do I change "NSDate date" to so that the user can input whatever title they want?

```c
(void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've generated the default MasterViewController project in Xcode.  I would recommend searching for tutorials on the UITableView or perhaps reading a book on iOS development.  Maybe someone can recommend one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new `UIAlertView` with plain text entry. You'll also have to change your table view cell to display an `NSString` instead of an `NSDate`. (Oh, and you have to adopt the `UIAlertViewDelegate` in the class.

```
-(void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{

    UIAlertView * getTitle = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil]; // should give proper cancel/accept buttons
    getName.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [getTitle show];
}


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    NSString * userEnteredThisString = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    [_objects insertObject:userEnteredThisString atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}
```